# How should I solve these inequalities?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, real-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

These are two inequalities from my assignments. I don't know if it is too difficult or I am not so good at inequalities but please help me with full answers.

1. Let $a$,$b$,$c$ be three real positive numbers, prove that

[image]

So first, to avoid typing too much character, I may write the LHS of the first problem in the form of $\sum\frac{a(a−2b+c)}{a×b+1}$, which I transformed to $\sum\frac{a^2+1}{a×b+1} + \sum\frac{a×c+1}{a×b+1}−6.$

It is easy to prove using a.m-g.m inequality that $\sum\frac{a×c+1}{a×b+1}\geq3.$

It is also clear that $\sum\frac{a^2+1}{a×b+1}\geq3$ by Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality. Q.E.D –

2. Let $x$,$y$,$z$ be three non-negative real numbers, prove that: 
   [image]

The second problem is a little more complicated, I think so I haven't finished it yet, but still, this is what I have worked on:

$\sum\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+3}}\leq\frac{3\sqrt3}{8}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\frac{3}{8}.$

According to the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, $\sqrt{(x^2+3)(1+3)}\geq x+3$,

$\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\geq x+y+z$; further transformations yield,

$\frac{3}{8}\sum(x+3)+\sum\frac{6}{x+3}\geq9$. This seems so obvious but how do I finish it?

---

**POST SCRIPT**
I really look forward to you posting your **full answers** rather than **comment** on this post. Please help with this

Comment: Post these inequalities in different topics and show please your attempts.

Comment: where should i post these inequalities?

Comment: Just open another topic. By the way, I solved your first problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I solved also your second problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts. Otherwise, this topic would be deleted.

Comment: okay, I will write it below.

Comment: So first, to avoid typing too much character, I may write the LHS of the first problem in the form of $\Sigma \frac{a\times (a-2b+c)}{a\times b +1}$, which I transformed to $\Sigma \frac{a^2+1}{a \times b +1}$ + $\Sigma \frac{a\times c +1}{a\times b +1}-6$. It is easy to prove using a.m-g.m inequality that $\Sigma \frac{a\times c +1}{a\times b +1} \ge 3$ . It is also clear that $\Sigma \frac{a^2+1}{a\times b +1} \ge 3$ by Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality. Q.E.D

Comment: The second problem is a little more complicated, I think so I haven't finished it yet, but still, this is what I have worked on:

Comment: $\Sigma$  $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+3}}$  $\le$ $\frac{3}{8}\times \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ + $\frac{3}{8}$ . According to the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, $\sqrt{(x^2+3)\times (1+3)}$ $\ge x+3$, $\sqrt{3\times (x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge x+y+z$; further transformations yield, $\frac{3}{8} \times \Sigma(x+3) +\Sigma \frac{6}{x+3} \ge 9$. This seems so obvious but how do I finish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem.

Your proof is beautiful!

My solution:

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+ac-2ab}{ab+1}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+ac+2}{ab+1}\geq6.$$
Now, by C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+ac+2}{ab+1}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ac+2)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ac+2)(ab+1)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ac+2)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+ac+2)(ab+1)}\geq6$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4-4a^3b+2a^3c+3a^2b^2-2a^2bc)+6\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)\geq0$$ and since
$$6\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)=3\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4-4a^3b+2a^3c+3a^2b^2-2a^2bc)\geq0,$$ which is smooth.

The second problem.

By your work it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{3}{8}\sum_{cyc}(x+3)+\sum_{cyc}\frac{6}{x+3}\geq9,$$ which is true by C-S and AM-GM:
$$\frac{3}{8}\sum_{cyc}(x+3)+\sum_{cyc}\frac{6}{x+3}=\frac{3}{8}\left(\sum_{cyc}(x+3)+16\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+3}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq \frac{3}{8}\left(\sum_{cyc}(x+3)+\frac{144}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x+3)}\right)\geq\frac{3}{8}\cdot2\cdot\sqrt{144}=9.$$